# How to thoroughly purge and reinstall postgresql on ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, uninstallation, apt-get

Somehow I've managed to completely bugger the install of postgresql on Ubuntu karmic.  I want to start over from scratch, but when I "purge" the package with apt-get it still leaves traces behind such that the reinstall configuration doesn't run properly.

After I've done:

```
apt-get purge postgresql
apt-get install postgresql
```

It said

```
Setting up postgresql-8.4 (8.4.3-0ubuntu9.10.1) ...
Configuring already existing cluster (configuration: /etc/postgresql/8.4/main, data: /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main, owner: 108:112)
Error: move_conffile: required configuration file     /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf does not exist
Error: could not create default cluster. Please create it manually with

  pg_createcluster 8.4 main --start

or a similar command (see 'man pg_createcluster').
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz (postmaster.1.gz) in auto mode.

Setting up postgresql (8.4.3-0ubuntu9.10.1) ...
```

I have a "/etc/postgresql" with nothing in it and "/etc/postgresql-common/" has a 'pg_upgradecluser.d' directory and root.crt and user_clusters files.

The /etc/passwd has a postgres user; the purge script doesn't appear to touch it.  There's been a bunch of symptoms which I work through only to expose the next.

Right this second, when I run that command "pg_createcluster..." it complains that '/var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf does not exist', so I'll go find one of those but I'm sure that won't be the end of it.

Is there not some easy one-liner (or two) which will burn it completely and let me start over?

Comment: Try one-click installer, it's more simple, its directories are not scattered in /etc/ and /var.  They are all stored in one directory

Answer (score 516, accepted):

## Option A

If your install isn't already damaged, you can drop unwanted PostgreSQL servers ("clusters") using `pg_dropcluster`. Use that in preference to a full purge and reinstall if you just want to restart with a fresh PostgreSQL instance.

```sh
$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
11  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
$ sudo systemctl stop postgresql@11-main
$ sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 11 main
$ sudo pg_createcluster --start 11 main
```

## Option B

If you really need to do a full purge and reinstall, first make sure PostgreSQL isn't running. `ps -C postgres` should show no results.

Now run:

```sh
apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*
```

to remove everything PostgreSQL from your system. Just purging the `postgres` package isn't enough since it's just an empty meta-package.

Once all PostgreSQL packages have been removed, run:

```
rm -r /etc/postgresql/
rm -r /etc/postgresql-common/
rm -r /var/lib/postgresql/
userdel -r postgres
groupdel postgres
```

You should now be able to:

```
apt-get install postgresql
```

or for a complete install:

```
apt-get install postgresql-8.4 postgresql-contrib-8.4 postgresql-doc-8.4
```

Comment: I've reworked the answer to remove advice to hand edit `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` in favour of safer `userdel` and `groupdel`. Also, rather than using `dselect` for hand-selection of packages, use an apt wildcard to match them reliably.

Comment: +1 for `pg_dropcluster`!! (Example Usage: `pg_dropcluster --stop 9.1 main`)

Comment: add libpq5 and libpq-dev to that purge list, that lib gave me A LOT of problems, until I reinstalled it on the right version

Comment: Works on Debian 8 with PostgreSQL 9.4 too.

Comment: I would also add `rm -r /var/log/postgresql`.

Answer (score 47):

I had a similar situation: I needed to purge postgresql 9.1 on a debian wheezy ( I had previously migrated from 8.4 and I was getting errors ).

What I did:

First, I deleted config and database

```
$ sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 9.1 main
```

Then removed postgresql

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge postgresql postgresql-9.1
```

and then reinstalled

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-9.1
```

In my case I noticed /etc/postgresql/9.1 was empty, and running `service postgresql start` returned nothing

So, after more googling I got to this command:

```
$ sudo pg_createcluster 9.1 main
```

With that I could start the server, but now I was getting log-related errors. After more searching, I ended up changing permissions to the /var/log/postgresql directory

```
$ sudo chown root.postgres /var/log/postgresql
$ sudo chmod g+wx /var/log/postgresql
```

That fixed the issue, Hope this helps

Answer (score 17):

Steps that worked for me on **`Ubuntu 8.04.2`** to remove **`postgres 8.3`**

1. **List All Postgres related packages**

   ```
   dpkg -l | grep postgres

   ii  postgresql                            8.3.17-0ubuntu0.8.04.1           object-relational SQL database (latest versi
   ii  postgresql-8.3                        8.3.9-0ubuntu8.04                object-relational SQL database, version 8.3
   ii  postgresql-client                     8.3.9-0ubuntu8.04                front-end programs for PostgreSQL (latest ve
   ii  postgresql-client-8.3                 8.3.9-0ubuntu8.04                front-end programs for PostgreSQL 8.3
   ii  postgresql-client-common              87ubuntu2                        manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versi
   ii  postgresql-common                     87ubuntu2                        PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
   ii  postgresql-contrib                    8.3.9-0ubuntu8.04                additional facilities for PostgreSQL (latest
   ii  postgresql-contrib-8.3                8.3.9-0ubuntu8.04                additional facilities for PostgreSQL
   ```
2. **Remove all above listed**

   ```
   sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql postgresql-8.3  postgresql-client  postgresql-client-8.3 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common  postgresql-contrib postgresql-contrib-8.3
   ```
3. **Remove the following folders**

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/
   sudo rm -rf /var/log/postgresql/
   sudo rm -rf /etc/postgresql/
   ```

Comment: Removing ALL Postgres related packages worked for me.  I had some 8.4 & 9.1 packages mixed up.  That combined with removing everything allowed me to finally reinstall 9.1 and have everything working with it.

Comment: Much easier with a wildcard: `apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*`

Answer (score 15):

```
apt-get purge postgresql*
```

is enough.

Comment: apt-get autoremove postgresql*

Answer (score 12):

I know an answer has already been provided, but dselect didn't work for me. Here is what worked to find the packages to remove:

```
# search postgr  | grep ^i
i   postgresql                      - object-relational SQL database (supported 
i A postgresql-8.4                  - object-relational SQL database, version 8.
i A postgresql-client-8.4           - front-end programs for PostgreSQL 8.4     
i A postgresql-client-common        - manager for multiple PostgreSQL client ver
i A postgresql-common               - PostgreSQL database-cluster manager       

# aptitude purge postgresql-8.4 postgresql-client-8.4 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common postgresql

rm -r /etc/postgresql/
rm -r /etc/postgresql-common/
rm -r /var/lib/postgresql/
```

Finally, editing /etc/passwd and /etc/group

Comment: These instructions worked on debian squeeze/sid

Comment: It's way easier to use a wildcard; see the updated 1st answer.

Answer (score 9):

Following ae the steps i followed to uninstall and reinstall. Which worked for me.

**First remove the installed postgres :-**

> sudo apt-get purge postgr*
>
> sudo apt-get autoremove

**Then  install 'synaptic':**

> sudo apt-get install synaptic
>
> sudo apt-get update

**Then install postgres**

> sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue for Ubuntu 13.04. These commands removed Postgres 9.1:

```
sudo apt-get purge postgresql
sudo apt-get autoremove postgresql
```

It occurs to me that perhaps only the second command is necessary, but from there I was able to [install Postgres 9.2](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-postgresql-9-2-on-ubuntu-13-04-server.html) (sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2).

Answer (score 0):

I was following the replies,
When editing /etc/group I also deleted this line:

```
ssl-cert:x:112:postgres
```

then, when trying to install postgresql, I got this error

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 syntax error: unknown group 'ssl-cert' in statoverride file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Putting the "ssl-cert:x:112:postgres" line back in /etc/group seems to fix it (so I was able to install postgresql)

Comment: In deleting the line you removed the entire "ssl-cert" group, which could create havoc with ssl. Instead, to remove postgres from the ssl-cert group, delete "postgres" from after the colon.

Comment: The original instructions were very mistaken in advising you to hand-edit `/etc/passwd`. *never do that*. Use the `userdel` and `groupdel` commands and you won't have that problem in future.

Answer (score -2):

I was facing same problem in my ubuntu 16.04

but i fixed that problem and it's very simple just follow these step and you will be able to install postgresql 10 in your system :

Add this to your sources.list:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib

deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib
```

after that add these link to your pgdg.list file if it's not there you have to create && add link && save it.

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main

deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main
```

then update your system

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and install that unmet dependencies :

```
apt-get install ssl-cert
```

that's it. now Install postgresql using these command

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-10
```