# Unable to connect to postgres in ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am trying to install postgresql on ubuntu.
I followed the steps from http://hocuspokus.net/2008/05/install-postgresql-on-ubuntu-804/.

And on typing the command :

```
psql template1
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
     Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: If you run `/etc/init.d/postgresql status` does it tell you its running?

Comment: It says "No such file or directory"

Comment: If you `ls -l /etc/init.d/ | grep postgres`, do you see see anything?

Comment: No I am able to see only postgresql-8.4.dpkg-dist

Comment: Looks like you messed up some part of the installation process.  Try removing then reinstalling. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748607/how-to-thoroughly-purge-and-reinstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu may be helpfull.

Comment: Hi,I installed and reinstalled again using apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client postgresql-contrib pgadmin3. Still I am not able to see   /etc/init.d/postgresql status
-bash: /etc/init.d/postgresql: No such file or directory

Comment: The postgres startup script would be /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.4.  What do you see now from `ls -l /etc/postgres*`?  Also what version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

psql template0

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that I had previously installed version 9.1, and 9.1 was still hogging the default port 5432.  I was able to find this with the command:

```
root@labs:/home/caleb# /etc/init.d/postgresql status
9.1/main (port 5432): down
9.2/main (port 5433): online
```

So I was able to see that my 9.2 database was running on port 5433.  So to connect, I had to explicitly specify port 5433:

```
psql -p 5433
```

Answer (score 0):

what resolved this error for me was deleting a file called postmaster.pid in the postgres directory. please see my question/answer using the following link for step by step instructions. my issue was not related to file permissions:

[psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573204/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-mac-os-x/13573207#13573207)

Answer (score 0):

You can also get in the CLI via this command:

`psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost`

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the error,

make a symbolic link to the /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432:

```
sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Thanks to this [post](https://sukhjitsehra.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/is-postgresql-server-is-running-and-accepting-and-issue-with-varpgsql_socket-s-pgsql-5432/)