# psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, postgresql

Upon restarting my Mac I got the dreaded Postgres error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

The reason this happened is because my macbook froze completely due to an unrelated issue and I had to do a hard reboot using the power button. After rebooting I couldn't start Postgres because of this error.

Comment: As a sanity check, make sure you have PG running on your machine

Comment: When you leave the answer please try to explain WHY this is happening, or how the Postgres system work so we're not all just trying random stuff.

Comment: `brew reinstall postgresql` https://stackoverflow.com/a/39781473/6086226 worked for me

Comment: brew reinstall postgresql this solved my issue

Answer (score 481, accepted):

WARNING: **If you delete postmaster.pid without making sure there are really no `postgres` processes running you, could permanently corrupt your database**. (PostgreSQL should delete it automatically if the postmaster has exited.).

SOLUTION: This fixed the issue--I deleted this file, and then everything worked!

```
/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

--

and here is how I figured out why this needed to be deleted.

1. I used the following command to see if there were any PG processes running. for me there were none, I couldn't even start the PG server:

   ```
   ps auxw | grep post
   ```
2. I searched for the file .s.PGSQL.5432 that was in the error message above. i used the following command:

   ```
   sudo find / -name .s.PGSQL.5432 -ls
   ```

this didn't show anything after searching my whole computer so the file didn't exist, but obviously `psql` "wanted it to" or "thought it was there".

3. I took a look at my server logs and saw the following error:

   ```
   cat /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
   ```

at the end of the server log I see the following error:

```
    FATAL:  pre-existing shared memory block (key 5432001, ID 65538) is still in use
    HINT:  If you're sure there are no old server processes still running, remove the shared memory block or just delete the file "postmaster.pid".
```

4. Following the advice in the error message, I deleted the postmaster.pid file in the same directory as server.log. This resolved the issue and I was able to restart.

So, it seems that my macbook freezing and being hard-rebooted caused Postgres to think that it's processes were still running even after reboot. Deleting this file resolved. Lots of people have similar issues but most the answers had to do with file permissions, whereas in my case things were different.

Comment: hopefully this answer ends up helping someone else out, and thank you to the person that upvoted it. despite the moderator who marked this question as a duplicate it is unique and useful. thanks stack overflow for the awesome site and the experts on here for sharing!

Comment: Just FWIW, deleting postmaster.pid is dangerous, you've got to be *really* sure there are no `postgres` processes running before you do it.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for posting your entire process rather than just the potentially destructive command!

Comment: Agreed. The answer about postmaster.pid is good, but each step of the process of figuring out if/where postgres is running, is *invaluable*. Thank you!

Comment: My postgres log on macos was at `/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log`.

Comment: Before deleting anything, try `brew reinstall postgresql`. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 233):

None of the above worked for me. I had to reinstall Postgres the following way :

- Uninstall postgresql with brew : `brew uninstall postgresql`
- `brew doctor` (fix whatever is here)
- `brew cleanup`
- Remove all Postgres folders :
- `rm -r /usr/local/var/postgres`
- `rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres`
- Reinstall postgresql with brew : `brew install postgresql`
- Start server : `brew services start postgresql`
- You should now have to create your databases... (`createdb`)

Comment: Worked for me, yet I did not have to remove an actual database and didn't have a folder in Application Support. I think the point was that some brew elements had broken symlinks while installing postgres. Fixing them and installing postgres again solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Neither this nor top answer worked for me, until I also ran `brew postgresql-upgrade-database`

Comment: These worked for me, except I didn't have to delete the old data.

Comment: To confirm: this deletes all your databases, correct? I was able to get by with just a `brew reinstall postgres`, confirming that the latest Homebrew Postgres major version number was the same as my current (broken) one.

Comment: @JacobFord are you saying that `brew reinstall postgresql` won't wipe your dbs?

Comment: Thanks! it is Old but gold!

Comment: The above provided solution worked on MacOS Monterey 12.1

Comment: Only change I added was also uninstalling `libpq` after uninstalling postgres:
`brew uninstall libpq`

Answer (score 100):

If you're on macOS and installed postgres via homebrew, try restarting it with

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

If you're on Ubuntu, you can restart it with either one of these commands

```
sudo service postgresql restart

sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 46):

Maybe this is unrelated but a similar error appears when you upgrade `postgres` to a major version using `brew`; using `brew info postgresql` found out this that helped:

```
To migrate existing data from a previous major version of PostgreSQL run:
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

Comment: This worked for me on going from 11 to 12 on Catalina

Comment: Worked for me as well

Answer (score 29):

Here is my way:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Comment: This worked for me when no other stopping and starting/restarting/reinstalling of Postgres using homebrew was done. Thanks @smartworld-dm

Comment: This is the soultion I always come back to.
I might add a alias that when I run `fix-my-postgresql` it will execute this :)

Comment: Any idea why I have to do this every time I reboot my PC?

Comment: Similar but different :) ...
brew services stop postgresql; rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid; brew services start postgresql

Answer (score 13):

The following commands helped me out. The issue was with the PostgreSQL data version. Once upgraded, it started working fine for me.

```
brew upgrade postgresql
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
brew services restart postgresql
```

Comment: Surprised !!! I just install postgresql on my MAC OS than on connect, connection fail. postgresql not running in background when I start as service, but after these commands. All works perfectly.

Comment: ^^^ this sequence did the trick for me, working solution for macOS as of June 2021. Thanks for documenting @satendra-rawat! If this doesn't work, it could potentially be a stale PID and then I'd try @smartworld-dm [solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57974029/4877027)

Comment: Just `brew upgrade postgresql@VERSION` did it for me, VERSION=11, etc.

Answer (score 12):

if your `postmaster.pid` is gone and you can't restart or anything, do this:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333317/pg-error-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused-is-the-server-running-o) initially

Comment: I worked for me! After deleting `postmaster.pid` and restarting postgres it was not created. I run this command, the file was recreated and the I can connect to DB again. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

For me, the solution was simply restart my computer.  I first tried restarting with Brew services and when that didn't work, restarting seemed like the next best option to try before looking into some of the more involved solutions.  Everything worked as it should after.

Answer (score 9):

Another class of reasons why this can happen is due to Postgres version updates.

You can confirm this is a problem by looking at the postgres logs:

```
tail -n 10000 /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log
```

and seeing entries like:

```
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 12, which is not compatible with this version 13.0.
```

In this case (assuming you are on Mac and using `brew`), just run:

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

(Oddly, it failed on run 1 and worked on run 2, so try it twice before giving up)

Comment:  This worked for me and I had to run it twice as well - first time it failed with the original error: 
```connection to database failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/usr/local/var/log/.s.PGSQL.50432"?
```

but running it a second time worked ¯\＿(ツ)＿/¯

Answer (score 8):

Hello world :)
**The best but strange way for me was to do next things.**
**1)** Download [postgres93.app](http://postgresapp.com/) or other version. Add this app into /Applications/ folder.

**2)** Add a row (command) into the file `.bash_profile` (which is in my home directory):

```
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/:$PATH
```

It's a PATH to `psql` from `Postgres93.app`. The row (command) runs every time console is started.

**3)** Launch `Postgres93.app` from `/Applications/` folder. It starts a local server (port is "5432" and host is "localhost").

**4)** After all of this manipulations I was glad to run `$ createuser -SRDP user_name` and other commands and to see that it worked! `Postgres93.app` can be made to run every time your system starts.

**5)** Also if you wanna see your databases graphically you should install `PG Commander.app`. It's good way to see your postgres DB as pretty data-tables

Of, course, it's helpful only for local server. I will be glad if this instructions help others who has faced with this problem.

Comment: The key here is adding Postgres to your path (step 2). That helped me. If you installed Postgres using Homebrew, you can add it to your path by adding the following line to your .bash_profile: `export PATH='/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/bin/':$PATH` – Keep in mind your version number may be different.

Answer (score 7):

This problema has many sources, and thus many answers. I've experienced each one of them.

1) If you have a crash of some sort, removing the /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid file is probably required as postgres may not have handled it properly.  But ensure that no process is running.

2) Craig Ringer has pointed out in other posts that Apple's bundling of postgreSQL leads to [pg gem installation issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225038/postgresql-adapter-pg-could-not-connect-to-server)  Setting the PATH environment variable is a solution.

3) Another solution, is to uninstall and reinstall the gem.  A brew update may be necessary as well.

If you stumble upon this post, if you can pinpoint one of the sources, you'll save time...

Comment: I'm glad I posted this.  Another crash & the answer can be retreived rather quickly...

Answer (score 5):

I was facing a similar issue here I solved this issue as below.

Actually the postgres process is dead, to see the status of postgres run the following command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgres status
```

It will says the process is dead`just start the process

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgres start
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, your answer helped me solve the same issue with some modifications: sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me after my Mac (High Sierra) froze and I had to manually restart it (press and hold the power button). All I had to do to fix it was  do a clean restart.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.
Most of the times, the problem is the fact that there's a leftover file

`/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

which works for most people, but my case was different - I tried googling this issue for last 3 hours, uninstalled postresql on OSX through brew, purged the database, nothing worked.

Finally, I noticed that I had an issue with brew that whenever I tried to install anything, it popped:

`Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /private/tmp/github_api_....`

or something like it at the end of an install.

I simply did `sudo chmod -R 777 /private/tmp` and it finally works!

I'm writing this down because this might be a solution for someone else

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem for `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.11`.

what worked for me -

remove postmaster.pid  --  `rm /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6/postmaster.pid`

restart postgres  -- `brew services restart postgresql@9.6`

If `postmaster.pid` doesn't exist or the above process doesn't work then run --

`sudo chmod 700  /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6`

Comment: This solution helped me with my regular issue with `postgresql@11`. I face this often issue whenever my laptop gets discharged and forced to restart.

Answer (score 4):

For those running into this issue on M1 macs, try deleting this file and then restarting the brew service:

`rm /opt/homebrew/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

Comment: in my case (Intel Mac OS Catalina) this file was here: /usr/local/var/postgresql@12/postmaster.pid

Answer (score 3):

My problem ended up being that I was using Gas Mask (a hosts file manager for Mac), and I didn't have an entry for localhost in the hosts file I was using.

I added:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

And that resolved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure why, but my Postgres installation got a little bit screwed and some files were deleted resulting in the error OP is showing.

Despite the fact that I am able to run commands like `brew service retart postgres` and see the proper messages, this error persisted.

I went through the postgres documentation and found that my file `/usr/local/var/postgres` was totally empty. So I ran the following:

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
```

It seems some configurations took place with that command.

Then it asked me to run this:

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

And that told me a postmaster.pid file already exists.

I just needed to know if brew would be able to pick up the configs I just ran, so I tested it out.

```
ls /usr/local/var/postgres
```

That showed me a postmaster.pid file. I then did `brew services stop postgresql`, and the postmaster.pid file disappeared. Then I did `brew services start postgresql`, and VIOLA, the file reappeared.

Then I went ahead and ran my app, which did in fact find the server, however my databases seem to be gone.

Although I know that they may not be gone at all - the new initialization I did may have created a new data_area, and the old one isn't being pointed to. I'd have to look at where that's at and point it back over or just create my databases again.

Hope this helps! Reading the postgres docs helped me a lot. I hate reading answers that are like "Paste this in it works!" because I don't know what the hell is happening and why.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and it was due to an incompatible version after upgrading from version 11 to 13.2

Checking error log at:

```
/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log
```

Showed me:

```
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 11, which is not compatible with this version 13.2.
```

To fix I ran:

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

And then started postresql with brew:

```
brew services start postgresql
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the log files.  Discovered that there was a lock on the database and this other SO answer helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49344641/1070718

Answer (score 2):

The causes of this error are many so first locate your log file and check it for clues. It might be at `/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log` or `/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log` or possibly elsewhere. If you installed with Homebrew you can find the location in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error.

All of this is done from the command line (no `sudo` calls at all)

1. I verified I had PostgreSQL installed `psql -V` (note that's a capital "V")
2. I attempted to connect to the server: `psql postgres`

### THIS IS WHERE I EXPERIENCED THE ERROR OF THIS STACK OVERFLOW QUESTION

After doing some research about possible fixes, I obviously had PostgreSQL installed, but I didn't have a default server in place.

What I had to do was [create a Custom Data Directory](https://dataschool.com/learn-sql/how-to-start-a-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x/#optional-creating-a-custom-data-directory)

As far as I can tell, creating the custom data directory is the same as having a default server in place.

Since this is a new machine (MacBook Pro 2021 using apple m1 chip), I wanted to find the easiest solution possible, and I believe this Custom Data Directory is just that. The remaining steps to fix this issue are as follows:

3. From the home directory, I created an empty directory `mkdir myData`
4. From the home directory, Initialized a server: `initdb myData` (throws a bunch of files into the myData directory)
5. `pg_ctl -D myData -l logfile start` (starts the server)
6. `psql postgres` (connects to the server)

So, as someone fairly new to PostgreSQL and databases and SQL in general, couple notes:

- It is possible to "quit" the connection to the server, using `\q` (while connected to the server, it's also possible to type "help")
- It is also possible to "stop" the server, as well with `pg_ctl -D myData stop`

At this point I now am certain I have PostgreSQL installed, have a server I can start and stop, and have the ability to connect to/disconnect from, that server.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same concern when connecting trying to start a PostgreSQL database server on **MacOS Monterey**.

When I run the command below to restart the PostgreSQL database server:

```
brew services restart PostgreSQL
```

It restarts but when I try to check the status of the PostgreSQL database server using the command below, I get an error:

```
Name       Status     User           File
mysql      started    promisepreston ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
nginx      started    promisepreston ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
postgresql error  256 root           ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

**Here's what worked for me**:

First, I checked the log file for the PostgreSQL database server to what was the cause of the error using the command below:

```
cat /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log
```

OR

```
nano /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log
```

The logs showed the following errors:

```
"root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.
The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
more information on how to properly start the server.
2022-01-25 19:01:06.051 WAT [29053] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2022-01-25 19:01:06.051 WAT [29053] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 13, which is not compatible with this version 14.1.
```

**For the root execution error** I had to run the following command to fix file permissions that when messed us when I ran `brew services` with the `sudo` command prefix. Replace `your-username` with your MacOS username (in my case my username was `promisepreston`:

```
# Stop postgresql
sudo brew services stop PostgreSQL

# In case service file is copied to ~/Library/LaunchAgents as well
brew services stop postgresql

# Fix permission of homebrew files
sudo chown -R your-username:admin $(brew --prefix)/*
```

**For the database files are incompatible with server** I had to simply upgrade the existing PostgreSQL data files which were created using version 13 to the latest PostgreSQL version on my computer which was 14.1 by running the following command below:

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

Afterwhich, I restarted the PostgreSQL database server:

```
brew services restart PostgreSQL
```

And then checked the status using the command below:

```
brew services list
```

Then I got the output below showing that everything was working fine:

```
Name          Status  User           File
mysql         started promisepreston ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
nginx         started promisepreston ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
postgresql    started promisepreston ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

**References**:  [Brew PostgreSQL Starts But Process Is Not Running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67700330/10907864)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `/var/log/`
and run cat `postgres.log`
Here you will find the reason for the failure of postgres.
If it is a smart shut down then probably your `icu4c` version (C++ library for Unicode) is not proper which is linked with `postgres`. So run the following commands.

`brew upgrade`
`brew cleanup`
This should work ;)

Comment: May have to run `brew style` afterwards if `brew cleanup` breaks Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to look up this post several times to solve this issue. There's another fix, which will also applies to similar issues with other running programs.

I just discovered you can use the following two commands.

$top

This will show all the currently running actions with their pid numbers. When you find postgres and the associated pid

$kill pid_number

Comment: Similar to `ps aux | grep \[p\]ostgres | awk '{ print $2 }'` to return the pid, or `kill $(ps aux | grep \[p\]ostgres | awk '{ print $2 }')` (on zsh `[]` must be escaped as `\[\]`, but not on bash)

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same issue as I have put my machine(`ubuntu`) for update and got below error:

> could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server
>   running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket
>   "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

After completing the updating process when I restart my system error gone. And its work like charm as before.. I guess this was happened as pg was updating and another process started.

Answer (score 0):

SUPER NEWBIE ALERT: I'm just learning web development and the particular tutorial I was following mentioned I have to install Postgres but didn't actually mention I have to ***run*** it as well... Once I opened the Postgres application everything was fine and dandy.

Answer (score 0):

@Jagdish Barabari's answer gave me the clue I needed to resolve this. Turns out there were two versions of postgresql installed while only one was running. Purging all postgresql files and reinstalling the latest version resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I removed /usr/lib from the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it worked.
I was working in dockerfile postgres:alpine.

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45454567/15067545 on my ubuntu system.

Command: `sudo service postgresql restart`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).