# Upgrade PostgreSQL 9.0 to 9.5 in Centos 7 does not work

Tags: postgresql, centos7, postgresql-9.0, postgresql-9.5

We have an enviroment with Postgres 9.0 and centos 6.2 and want to migrate to Postgres 9.5 and Centos 7.2.

We install a new server with Centos 7.2 and Postgres 9.0.23 and restore a database buckup and it works just fine. Connection works ok.

Then we install Postgresql 9.5 to run `pg_upgrade` (just yum).... We tried to connect to database (9.0) ... and we get...

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

we uninstall postgresql 9.5 and connection to database works fine again :(

Any idea!?

Tks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868730/socket-file-var-pgsql-socket-s-pgsql-5432-missing-in-mountain-lion-os-x-ser

Comment: Did you configure 9.5 instance to bind to a different port?

Comment: I just install the software. There's no 9.5 instance runing. I don't even execute initdb for the 9.5 version. I tried other ports but it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

I post my own answer....

ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432

Tks all!