# psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-mavericks

When I attempted to start my local Postgres server this afternoon, I was greeted with the following error message:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I attempted to follow the instructions in the top rated answer on the following question: [psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573204/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-mac-os-x); however, the file `/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` does not appear to exist.

I'm running on OS X Mavericks.

---

I'm not entirely sure if this will help narrow it down, but the last thing I did last night was try an OS X system utility called Yasu (http://yasuapp.net/). I can only assume when it restarted the system, that's when something went wrong.

Comment: Is a known issue with OSX. Take a look at the "related" section on the right.

Comment: I'm aware that the issue has been encountered before. The solution that is usually presented, however, doesn't appear to be working in my case.

Comment: Which "usual solution"? There are several.

Comment: Deleting `postmaster.pid` was the most frequently accepted solution that I've encountered. The file doesn't appear to exist on my system.

Comment: Post your postgres server logs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a command like `( netstat -ln; ps -ef ) | egrep '(postgres)|(postmaster)|(5432)'` to try to determine whether or not an instance of the postgres server is running.

If the postmaster is not running, remove the *postmaster.pid* file and restart the database.  Do not remove the *postmaster.pid* file without making sure the database is not running, and note that removing the *postmaster.pid* file without starting the database is pointless.

It may be wise to open your *postgresql.conf* file and see if the *listen_addresses*, *port*, *unix_socket_directory*, *unix_socket_group*, and *unix_socket_permissions* settings might be a source of issues.

Since the error message referenced specifically mentions the socket file, look most closely at *unix_socket_directory*, *unix_socket_group*, and *unix_socket_permissions*.

If *unix_socket_directory* is pointing somewhere other than */tmp*, then various workarounds exist.

Alternatively, and presuming that the server is running, one might try to locate the socket file without looking in the *postgresql.conf* file, though this might make it a bit harder to address permissions, port, etc. issues.  A tool like `locate`, `find`, etc., may be used in conjunction with `sudo` or by the *root* user.

```
$ sudo find /tmp /var -name .s.PGSQL.5432
```

Presuming that the location of the *.s.PGSQL.5432* file issue is the root cause of your problem, specifying the socket file location on the `psql` command-line is probably the most straightforward workaround.  In example, if the *.s.PGSQL.5432 file is in */var/pgsql_socket* directory as it is on some systems, try this, but, of course, use the actual directory where *.s.PGSQL.5432* is located:

```
$ pgsql -h /var/pgsql_socket
```

If the *.s.PGSQL.5432* file IS in */tmp*, then the problem is more likely one of permissions, and consulting the *postgresql.conf* file is advised, and probably the user attempting the `psql` command will have to be added to a group that has access to the socket file.  (Remember, log out and back in after changing group membership.)

Comment: the OP stated: "the file /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid does not appear to exist" and this solution suggest deleting that file :-/

Comment: The answer avoids an assuming that because the "/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid does not appear to exist" that the most popular solution is invalid. The OP's wording indicates uncertainty. A postmaster.pid file might exist elsewhere due to a settings issue. This is taken into consideration. I don't think that the answer is invalidated on the point that the OP is not sure that the postmaster.pid file is an issue as the question did not provide evidence the the system configuration settings place the postmaster.pid file in the specified folder where the file was not found.