# postgresql could not connect to server - No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed postgresql on Ubuntu 16.04, when I run `psql` command this error appears:

> could not connect to server: No such file or directory.
>   Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain
>   socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I tried to restart and reload postgres service but the error shows every time.

Comment: Postgres server creates this file on startup. Thus, your server isn't running. Please look into the system or postgres logs to find details, why your server doesn't start.

Comment: `pg_ctl status`?..

Comment: Please provide your error message. Which user are you attempting to start the service as. YOu must be the 'postgres' user.

Answer (score 3):

I got same errors in Ubuntu 14.04 and it worked for me.
Try to restart Postgres service

```
$ sudo service postgresql restart
```

or

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

1) go to `/var/log/postgresql` and open log file

if you see error similar to this in your log file

`FATAL:  private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key"` has group or world access

`DETAIL:  File must have permissions u=rw (0600)` or less if owned by the database user, or permissions `u=rw,g=r (0640)` or less if owned by root.

a) execute the following commands to change the permission (make sure to change the key file name if it is diff for you)

```
$ sudo chown postgres /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
$ sudo chgrp postgres /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
$ sudo chmod 740 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

now restart the service

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

it should show this messge
[ ok ] Restarting postgresql (via systemctl): postgresql.service.

now type these commands to verify

```
$ sudo su - postgres
$ psql
```

You should see this message

```
root@imp-itpl0023:/etc/ssl/private# su - postgres
postgres@imp-itpl0023:~$ psql
psql (10.3 (Ubuntu 10.3-1.pgdg16.04+1))
Type "help" for help.
```