# Could not connect to server. Postgresql connecting to unix domain socket

Tags: postgresql, sockets

My site was running perfectly. I switched off my server to upgrade memory and cores. After turning it on again, i'm greeted by a 500 error. After switching to debug mode, it returns the following:

```
OperationalError at /
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433"?
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://mysite.nl/
Django Version: 1.6.11
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433"?
Exception Location: /data_nfs/opensurfaces/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect, line 130
Python Executable:  /data_nfs/opensurfaces/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, with a django applicaiton hosted by nginx, gunicorn and postgresql. It appears I need to connect the socket to the server? How Can i do this?

A seemingly related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573204/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-mac-os-x) tells me to remove a file, but I don't have this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `sudo service postgresql restart` doesn't do the trick. Instead I restart it using `sudo -u postgres /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`, which does work.