# Postgres in Rails5 Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I opened the rails console and called the DatabaseTable, But it failed.
I followed

[psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573204/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-mac-os-x)

I tried to open postgres and I got the error.

```
$ psql

psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

and I called the log to observe what happened.

```
$ tail -f /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log

FATAL:  database "ror_development" does not exist
ERROR:  database "ror_development" already exists
STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE "ror_development" ENCODING = 'utf8'
ERROR:  database "ror_test" already exists
STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE "ror_test" ENCODING = 'utf8'
FATAL:  database "harem_backend_development" does not exist
LOG:  received smart shutdown request
LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
LOG:  shutting down
LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I can't understand what happened to my sql, and how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure postgres is running on MacOS.**

If you installed postgres using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), you should be able to start it using brew:

```
brew services start postgresql
```

Otherwise, you can start it with:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

For more info on how to install and use postgres in MacOS, read [this guide](https://www.codementor.io/devops/tutorial/getting-started-postgresql-server-mac-osx).

**Setup your Rails database (Rails >= 5)**

Once postgres is started, you will be able to setup your Rails database.

To create the database:

```
 rails db:create
```

To migrate the database:

```
 rails db:migrate
```

To seed the database:

```
 rails db:seed
```

To create and seed the database:

```
 rails db:setup
```

Finally, to drop (delete) the database:

```
 rails db:drop
```

For Rails < 5, replace `rails` with `bundle exec rake` in the above commands.

For more info on setting up and configuring a database with Rails, read the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database).

Comment: I got new error log `waiting for server to start....2017-12-16 06:39:07.180 CST [12387] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2017-12-16 06:39:07.180 CST [12387] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.5, which is not compatible with this version 10.1.
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.`

Comment: It looks like you have an incompatible version of postgres installed.  You may have tried to install it twice.  If you can afford to lose the existing databases, you may want to uninstall all versions of postgres and reinstall them.

Answer (score 1):

From the log messages it seems your Postgres is not running(It seems to like postgres process is manually killed.) . Try starting Postgres again

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
psql
```

Comment: I got new error log `waiting for server to start....2017-12-16 06:39:07.180 CST [12387] FATAL: database files are incompatible with server 2017-12-16 06:39:07.180 CST [12387] DETAIL: The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.5, which is not compatible with this version 10.1. stopped waiting pg_ctl: could not start server Examine the log output.`