# Setting up PostgreSQL, could not connect to database postgres

Tags: file, postgresql, directory

I will create a django app on Debian 7 with postgreSQL 9.2.
I created a droplet in digital ocean. I updated and upgraded the system.
I used the following command

```
sudo aptitude install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

to install postgresql.

When I changed user to postgres and I wanted to create a new db user with `createuser -P`

I filled all the fields it wanted but it came up with this error:

```
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I tried same process a few times with new droplets in Ubuntu 12.04 and Debian 7.

What should I do?
I want to use Debian 7, so I prefer solutions with Debian.
I am new at this stuff so be explanatory please.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use `initdb` to create a postgres DB cluster ?

Comment: How should I do it? :)

Comment: Use postgres manual : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-initdb.html or just google `postgres initdb`

Comment: "Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket ..." <-- check this. Start with "ps -u postgres" to see if there's anything running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out with fixing locale problem and reinstall PostgreSQL

First:
http://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment

Second:
[How to thoroughly purge and reinstall postgresql on ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748607/how-to-thoroughly-purge-and-reinstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu)

Set up the locale and make a clean installation for postgreSQL.

Thanks!