# error with postgresql datababse : Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sockets

When I run the `rake db:migrate` or run the `rails s` command, I get the same error:

```
Error : could not connect to server: 
No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I get the error in the browser when I try `rails s`.

This is my database.yml

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode

pool: 5

development:
<<: *default
database: books_development




test:
<<: *default
database: books_test



production:
<<: *default
database: books_production
username: abd
password: <%= ENV['BOOKS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Note : I have the databases `books_development`; `books_test`
 ; and the postresql are running without problems when I try `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start`

I did run:

```
create database books_development;
create database books_test;
```

in the psql console. And it said that it's done successfully

I tried a lot of solutions and I spent yesterday looking for a solution and no solution in the related questions solved my error.

I have postgresql-9.4 (the latest) and xubuntu 14.04

Any Ideas?

Comment: Check this thread - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=869080 - maybe you'll find any hints...

Comment: I told I spent the whole yesterday looking for a solution , and of course I tried that thread ; it didn't work for me :(

Comment: Thank you I solved It .

I Just created a softlink using

`sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`

and then edited the
`/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf`
( If you have another version of  postgresql you have to change 9.4 in the path)
from

`local                         all                    postgres              peer`

To:

`local                         all                    postgres              md5`

Comment: It might be worth if you created an answer based on your comment, and mark it as the proper one - just for future references. Best!

Comment: in my case in /etc there is no postgresql folder...any idea what to do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The convention for PostgreSQL packaged for Debian or Debian derivatives such as Ubuntu is to use `/var/run/postgresql` as the directory for Unix domain sockets. On the other hand the convention for self-compiled postgres client libs is to use `/tmp`, unless self-configured otherwise.

So the usual root cause of this mismatch between both is a mix of self-compiled client-side stuff with pre-compiled server-side packages (even if client and server are installed on the same machine, client-side and server-side are still distinct and can be out of sync).

Soft-linking from `/tmp` to this directory as suggested by the asker works except that the link will be lost at every reboot, because in general `/tmp` is emptied on reboot.

A better option would be to add as an entry in `database.yml`:

- either `host: /tmp` if the real socket path is `/tmp` (self-compiled server,  packaged client)
- or `host: /var/run/postgresql` if the real socket path `/var/run/postgresql/` (packaged server, self-compiled client).

When the value in the host field starts with a slash character, the postgres library knows that it's the location of a directory for local sockets rather than a hostname. The filename inside the directory `.s.PGSQL.portnumber` is generated and must not be specified, only the directory.

Another possibility is to configure the self-compiled software packages as closely as possible to Debian, overriding the defaults as they do.

Comment: Thank you, adding the `host: /tmp` in `database.yml` does work very nice :) ; but I am afraid from the deploying to Heroku . Is it fine ? will the app work fine after deploying to heroku ?

Comment: Yes, you may have to adapt `database.yml` for heroku, but nothing to be afraid of. Just read and follow their documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-ruby

Comment: Thank you, adding the `host: /tmp` for development in database.yml does work for Rails 6, Postgres 12, macOS 10 Mojave (haven't gone to Catalina yet; waiting for 2 weeks without fixes). Ran into this problem (slight difference: `Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"') upgrading from Postgres 10 to 12. However now I have another problem with the upgrade; but that's another posting.

Answer (score 8):

> That means your **Postgres** server is not running.

Check **Postgres** Service status from Terminal

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

Enable **Postgres** Service, If not started

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

**OR**

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Now your command should work, If **Postgres** Service is successfully started.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same `Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket “/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432”?` error when typing `psql` into the postgres user in Ubuntu 14.04. I could not find an existing working solution.

The short answer for me was: my install made a `var/pgsql_socket` directory but no configuration files knew about it.

1) Find the `postgres.conf` file (it was in `etc/postgresql/9.6/main` for me)
2) change to `listen_addresses = '*'` 
3) add another unix socket directory 
`unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql, /var/pgsql_socket' # comma-separated list of directories` 
4) at this point, sudo service postgresql start attempted to start but did not have authority to create the lock file. 
`* The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2016-10-05 17:14:55 CEST [28472-1] FATAL:  could not create lock file "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": Permission denied
2016-10-05 17:14:55 CEST [28472-2] LOG:  database system is shut down` 
5) Change permissions ( found from [Mark Berry's comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748607/how-to-thoroughly-purge-and-reinstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu) ) 
`$ sudo chown root.postgres /var/pgsql_socket`
`$ sudo chmod g+wx /var/pgsql_socket`
6) `sudo service postgresql start` 
 `sudo -i -u postgres` 
 `psql`

That finally worked for me

Comment: Thanks so much! I was running into problems restoring my 9.4 db to my 9.6 install and this fixed my problems!

Comment: I am facing  this "chown: cannot access '/var/pgsql_socket': No such file or directory"

Answer (score 4):

I solved It . I Just created a softlink using :

`sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`

and then edited the

/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf

( If you have another version of postgresql you have to change 9.4 in the path)

From:

`local      all           postgres              peer`

To:

`local      all           postgres              md5`

Comment: I get `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432’: File exists`

Comment: then delete it by `rm /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` and try again :)

Comment: @adyouri   hey i tryed this But it give me error
sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
ERROR BELOW
ln: failed to access '/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432': Permission denied

Answer (score 2):

The exact same symptom can be caused by a stale lock file `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock`. One of the symptoms of this is `psql` reporting

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>           Is the server running locally and accepting
>           connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

even though there is clearly a socket with this path available as reported by `netstat -lp --protocol=unix | grep postgres`

The problem can be solved by removing the lock file and restarting postgresql. This is definitely less invasive than a purge and re-install.

```
sudo rm /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X I usually get this error when my computer shuts down incorrectly, for example, due to power failure.

The solution I use is pretty simple and works 100% of the time:

```
# Find the postgres config folder
cd /usr/local/var/postgres

# remove file
rm postmaster.pid

# restart postgres
brew services restart postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

When I run into this error, my Postgres server was actually listening on a different port (5433) and not 5432.
To solve this, add

```
port: 5433
```

to your `database.yml` file to instruct rails to use the same

Comment: Wow. Same here. Simple solution

Answer (score 1):

Running `pg_lsclusters` will list all the postgres clusters running on your device
eg:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.6 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

if the status is down run

```
#format is pg_ctlcluster <version> <cluster> <action>
sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.6 main start
```

If this process is not successfull it will throw the error.
My error was(You can see the error log on `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log`)

```
FATAL: could not access private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key": Permission denied
Try adding `postgres` user to the group `ssl-cert`
```

make sure that `postgres` is the owner of `/var/lib/postgresql/version_no/main`
eg: `sudo chown postgres -R /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/`

It happened to me and it turned out that I removed erroneously the Postgres user from "ssl-cert" group. Run the below code to fix the user group issue and fixing the permissions

```
#set user to group back with
sudo gpasswd -a postgres ssl-cert

# Fixed ownership and mode
sudo chown root:ssl-cert  /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
sudo chmod 740 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

# now postgresql starts! (and install command doesn't fail anymore)
sudo service postgres restart
```