# ProgrammingError at / relation "main_post" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql

Hello I'm using django and postgresql. And I'm getting the above error. I have database set up like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'django_db',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD':'xxxx',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
    }
}
```

for problems like this with sqlite, I could've just delete db(mydatabase) but this time I can't see where my db is.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.8.4
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main',
 'tastypie')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/ebagu/main/views.py" in index
  47.               post_list = sorted(post_list, key=lambda x: x.get_score(), reverse=True)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  162.         self._fetch_all()
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  965.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  238.         results = compiler.execute_sql()
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  840.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64. .cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/younggue/Desktop/ebagu1/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  97.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /
Exception Value: relation "main_post" does not exist
LINE 1: ...id", "main_post"."views", "main_post"."slug" FROM "main_post...
                                                             ^
```

Output from `sqlflush`:

```
BEGIN;
TRUNCATE "django_admin_log", "auth_permission", "auth_group", "auth_group_permissions", "django_session", "auth_user_groups", "auth_user_user_permissions", "main_category", "tastypie_apiaccess", "main_vote", "auth_user", "tastypie_apikey", "django_content_type";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"django_admin_log"','id'), 1, false);
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"auth_permission"','id'), 1, false);
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"auth_group"','id'), 1, false);
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"auth_user"','id'), 1, false);
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"django_content_type"','id'), 1, false);
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"main_category"','id'), 1, false);
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"main_post"','id'), 1, false);
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"main_vote"','id'), 1, false);
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"tastypie_apiaccess"','id'), 1, false);
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"tastypie_apikey"','id'), 1, false);

COMMIT;
```

Output from `syncdb`/`migrate`:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, froala_editor, messages, crispy_forms
  Apply all migrations: userena, sessions, admin, guardian, tastypie, auth, contenttypes, accounts, main, easy_thumbnails
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack error? The title error is a little ambiguous.

Comment: @AaronLayfield opps sorry just updated it

Comment: Is main_post reference to anything within your Django App? I see you have an app called `main` and post sounds like it might be a model within this app. The SQL error is suggesting this is missing. Try performing a `python manage.py sqlflush` and then a `migrate` and `makemigrations` just to check that the Db is accurately representing the models from the app.

Comment: Also, please try a `syncdb`.

Comment: I tried all of those but same error, I'm not sure where main_post is from....I have an app named main and model named Post. I see it's from     post_list = Post.objects.all()
    post_list = sorted(post_list, key=lambda x: x.get_score(), reverse=True)

Comment: @AaronLayfield also with sqflash I get the above ones

Comment: I googled around, and it says I need to remove host and port in settings.py and rerun db...but don't I need those?

Comment: I'll be home in half hour, I can probably provide more context then. But, yes, main_post will be reference to the Post model. If you can, try to query the DB to check if the table exists (main_post). Try check the manage.py DB options, one of them should force drop the table and recreate (if you don't mind losing the data in the table).

Comment: yeah sure, do you mind helping me out through chat on stackoverflow after like 30min?

Comment: @mikebraa your model's table seems to be missing in db. What is the output for running migrate/syncdb commands?

Comment: @tutuDajuju hello I updated, please help me

Comment: Try `makemigrations main` followed by `migrate`.

Comment: shouldn’t it print the created tables? try with `--verbosity 3`. Which migrations do you see in the main app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstalling postgresql with this method: [How to thoroughly purge and reinstall postgresql on ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748607/how-to-thoroughly-purge-and-reinstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu) then reinstalling with help from [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OD3oeodNms) fixed the problem.