# Could not access database on Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I got an error when I tried to access my database on postgresql:

```
sudo -i -u psquser psql psqdb
```

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory  Is the
>   server running locally and accepting  connections on Unix domain
>   socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I don't know what cause the problem since before that I could access it as normal.

As this problem before, I tried to reinstall `postgresql` by following this instrunction [How to thoroughly purge and reinstall postgresql on ubuntu? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748607/how-to-thoroughly-purge-and-reinstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu). It took me lot of time since I have to to configured almost everything from scratch.

Is there an alternative better that I can solve this problem? Could I know what is the rootcause of this.

PS: I hosted this server on digital ocean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres another thread that suggest Postgresql is not always running, check by;

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

Comment: thanks, It got rid of error message above, but when I tried access database again `sudo -i -u psquser psql psqdb`, I got role 'psquser' does not exist.

Comment: even I try access via default user 'postgres' `psql -U postgres` to alter user 'psquser' also not work, it ask for password of user 'postgres'. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm ok, you might need to check the pg_hba.conf for your psqdb setting and the postgresql logs. But wait, shouldn't you be using upper case -U psquser ?

Comment: after google around, I have changed `pg_hba.cong` to `local   all   postgres  ident` and manually created role and privilege for user `psquser`. Then, I was enable access database and restore it successfully. Thanks very much for your answer, it really helped I will accept it :)