# How do I configure postgresql to find the config files in a different location?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

On a Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) machine, I used `apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib` to install postgresql 9.5 anew. To my surprise, by default it's finding the config files in the data directory as evidenced by:

```
postgres=# show hba_file;
                 hba_file                 
------------------------------------------
 /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
```

I would prefer they be in /etc/postgresql/9.5/main
I have searched the docs for this answer and it eludes me.

How can I configure the server to always find them there, even after a restart (hence, making the configuration "sticky"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The confusion stemmed from something being wrong with my install. 
I followed the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748607/how-to-thoroughly-purge-and-reinstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu) to utterly remove and reinstall postgresql cleanly.

Once I performed the clean install, I can see that the configuration file is being found in the expected path as evidenced below:

```
ps aux | grep postgresql
postgres  4386  0.0  0.2 294872 22884 ?        S    16:35   0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
```